# Why near-cli can't find my contract method?

Tags: nearprotocol

So I have this function implemented for my Contract

```
#[payable]
fn send_message(mut self, message: &str, receiver: &str) {
```

When I try to call it using near-cli

`near call v1.messenger.ijelis.testnet send_message '{"message": "test","sender": "iejlis.near"}' --account-id ijelis.testnet`

It gives me out this

```
Scheduling a call: v1.messenger.ijelis.testnet.send_message({"message": "test","sender": "iejlis.near"})
Doing account.functionCall()
Receipt: DDXubobUugwsGnr9GqXxMv7PJqT3YsLjTn14xWML4vx
    Failure [v1.messenger.ijelis.testnet]: Error: Contract method is not found
ServerTransactionError: Contract method is not found
    at Object.parseResultError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/near-cli/node_modules/near-api-js/lib/utils/rpc_errors.js:31:29)
    at Account.signAndSendTransactionV2 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/near-cli/node_modules/near-api-js/lib/account.js:160:36)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async scheduleFunctionCall (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/near-cli/commands/call.js:57:38)
    at async Object.handler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/near-cli/utils/exit-on-error.js:52:9) {
  type: 'MethodNotFound',
  context: undefined,
  index: 0,
  transaction_outcome: {
    proof: [ [Object] ],
    block_hash: 'G4QJ5PPykJWieCyi9P5Rzxu73t1YCKLGKnWL7Z5nUbhd',
    id: 'ExJyHwyCpjrFBXGXyr35Y6itkTPVpN1MtE4RnDbo2HBz',
    outcome: {
      logs: [],
      receipt_ids: [Array],
      gas_burnt: 2428039504502,
      tokens_burnt: '242803950450200000000',
      executor_id: 'ijelis.testnet',
      status: [Object],
      metadata: [Object]
    }
  }
}
```

What Am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I tried to deploy it using near-create-app interface, and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

seems you did not deploy the contract to this account.

check like this:

#### 1. is there *anything* deployed to the account?

Use NEAR CLI to quickly view account state (https://docs.near.org/docs/tools/near-cli#near-state)

```
near state v1.messenger.ijelis.testnet send_message
```

**Result**

```json
{
  amount: '2099882635532834400000000',
  locked: '0',
  code_hash: 'E8jZ1giWcVrps8PcV75ATauu6gFRkcwjNtKp7NKmipZG',
  storage_usage: 268,
  storage_paid_at: 0,
  block_height: 74201501,
  block_hash: '46fdR4oFfEDDuNmLMM8Le6FbKPR3VG5zzNni7u9uE3XQ',
  formattedAmount: '2.0998826355328344'
}
```

**Conclusion**

Yes, the account has *something* deployed to it because the value of `code_hash` is not the default `11111111111111111111111111111111` but `E8jZ1giWcVrps8PcV75ATauu6gFRkcwjNtKp7NKmipZG` which is a base58 encoded sha256 digest of the contract byte code, a fingerprint of the data deployed to the available "contract slot" on the account

#### 2. so what is deployed to the account exactly?

Use the API to view contract code: https://docs.near.org/docs/api/rpc/contracts#view-contract-code

```
http post https://rpc.testnet.near.org jsonrpc=2.0 id=dontcare method=query \
  params:='{
    "request_type": "view_code",
    "finality": "final",
    "account_id": "v1.messenger.ijelis.testnet"
  }'
```

**Result**

```json
{
    "id": "dontcare",
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "result": {
        "block_hash": "48uCNbhhB9FSg35bJgMDvTpjS5f9n4jrnU4MmMmbHsqj",
        "block_height": 74201992,
        "code_base64": "AGFzbQEAAAAEBQFwAQEBBQMBABAGGQN/AUGAgMAAC38AQYCAwAALfwBBgIDAAAsHJQMGbWVtb3J5AgAKX19kYXRhX2VuZAMBC19faGVhcF9iYXNlAwI=",
        "hash": "E8jZ1giWcVrps8PcV75ATauu6gFRkcwjNtKp7NKmipZG"
    }
}
```

**Conclusion**

`AGFzbQEAAAAEBQFwAQEBBQMBABAGGQN/AUGAgMAAC38AQYCAwAALfwBBgIDAAAsHJQMGbWVtb3J5AgAKX19kYXRhX2VuZAMBC19faGVhcF9iYXNlAwI=` looks way too small to be a contract, especially one written in Rust (they're usually a little bigger than AssemblyScript contracts)

This base64 encoded string decodes to the following [WAT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/Understanding_the_text_format)

```lisp
(module
  (table $T0 1 1 funcref)
  (memory $memory (export "memory") 16)
  (global $g0 (mut i32) (i32.const 1048576))
  (global $__data_end (export "__data_end") i32 (i32.const 1048576))
  (global $__heap_base (export "__heap_base") i32 (i32.const 1048576)))
```

So the contract you *think* is there is not actually there.

#### Solution

Deploy the contract to the account `v1.messenger.ijelis.testnet`

---

Note: the WAT above was generated in two steps:

(1). `echo "AGFzbQEAAAAEBQFwAQEBBQMBABAGGQN/AUGAgMAAC38AQYCAwAALfwBBgIDAAAsHJQMGbWVtb3J5AgAKX19kYXRhX2VuZAMBC19faGVhcF9iYXNlAwI=" | base64 -d > contract.wasm`

(2). upload Wasm file to  https://webassembly.github.io/wabt/demo/wasm2wat/

Comment: It looks like the problem is with my code, as I uploaded my contract again and nothing changed, using this command: `./near-cli add contract-code network testnet account v1.messenger.ijelis.testnet contract-file /home/inojelis/messenger-is-near/contract/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/messenger.wasm no-initialize sign-private-key [public and private keys omitted]` [which works](https://v.ht/lKbO). So here's the whole code on [github](https://github.com/Voodlaz/mhek)(look at the contract folder, because I'm not using the react frontend at all, I'm too lazy to remove it)

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you use `#[near_bindgen]` derive macro on your contract impl block to make pub contract methods visible.